# loop's counter i as I++ vs. i+1 as position in an array

Tags: java

I've made a loop with i as it's counter variable.
Inside that loop I'm comparing cells of an array.
I'm wondering what's the difference between array[i++] (or array[++i]) to array[i+1].
Since i++ (or ++i) don't work in the wanted way while i+1 does (a little bag which drove me crazy).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `array[i++]` will evaluate `array[i]` and increment `i`.
- `array[++i]` will increment `i` and *then* evaluate `array[i]` (so it gives you the next element)
- `array[i+1]` will give you the next element without incrementing `i`

Personally I try to avoid using side-effects like this - it means when I read the code later, I always have to slow down to make sure I get everything in the right order.

If you're already in a loop which is incrementing `i`, then incrementing `i` in the array access expression *as well* would mean that each loop iteration would increment `i` twice.

Answer (score 7):

`i++`, `++i`, and `i+1` are all different expressions (or operations). You should consult your favourite Java reference to learn about the difference.

(In short: `i++` increments `i` but returns the original value, `++i` increments `i` and returns the new value, `i+1` does not increment `i` but returns the value of `i+1`.)

As to why exactly your loop does not work the way you expect it to: this can not be answered without actually seeing your code—quite logical. My assumption would be that you either used the expressions wrong and/or that you incremented `i` twice per loop.

Comment: That I know, but why does ++i (a copy of the increment of i by one) doesn't work as i+1 the value of adding one to i?

Comment: That still depends on your code. Show it and we can tell you what’s wrong with it.

Comment: @baruch1mekonen: because when using `++i`, `i` gets incremented by one and it's *probably* also being incremented a second time in the loop. So next time you use it, it's incremented by 2 instead of one.
`i+1` results in the same value but does not increment (the content of `i`).

Answer (score 2):

`array[i++]` will give you the same as `array[i]` and then increment `i`. `array[++i]` will give you the same as `array[i+1]` and increment `i`. `array[i+1]` won't actually change the value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

- `i++`: increase the value stored in `i` by one, and return the old value.
- `++i`: increase the value stored in `i` by one, and return the new value.
- `i+1`: return the sum of `i` and `1`, without changing the value stored in `i`

Now consider what happens if, as I suspect, you have code that looks like

```
for ( i = 0; i < something; i++ )
{
   dosomething(i++);
}
```

the values of `i` passed to `dosomething()` will be
0
2
4
8
.
.

since every iteration of the loop, `i` is incremented once in the `for()` line and once in the `dosomething()` line, and the `dosomething()` call is given the value `i` had before it was incremented. If the behaviour actually desired is for `dosomething()` to be called with the sequence
1
2
3
4
.
.
then you need to avoid updating `i` with the result of adding 1 to it in the loop body:
    for ( i = 0; i < something; i++ )
    {
       dosomething(i+1);
    }

or even

```
for ( i = 1; i < (something+1); i++ )
{
   dosomething(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array[i++]` means "take the array element with index i, then increment i".
`array[i+1]` means "take the array element with index i+1, do not modify i".

Answer (score 0):

Not working properly because you are incrementing i twice in each loop.

So if your array is `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` and you printed `array[++i]` starting at i=0, it will print  "2,4,6," then throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsExcpetion`, if the array is `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` it will print "2,4,6,8"

Better be away from `++` on the loop counter, except if you really mean it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define `i=0`, then

- `i++` will return `0` and afterwards increment `i` to `1`
  (post increment: returns value, afterwards increase)
- `++i` will increment `i` to `1` and afterwards return `1`
  (pre increment: increases, afterwards return value)
- `ì+1` will **not** increment `i` and return `1`
  (addition: only return the result, doesn't touch the variable)

I assume, you don't want to increment i by itself, only add 1 to access an index with a different offset.